# .net mvc keybindings poster

Tags: asp.net-mvc, key-bindings, poster

I've been looking for some asp.net mvc keybinding posters but can only seem to find ones for VS 2010 which dont include any MVC specific things.

Is there any out there? Or what would be the easiest way to make one for myself?

I'm using resharper as well but that also doesnt seem to have a specific poster for mvc.